# Change border-bottom color using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, border

How to change the color of the bottom border using jQuery?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
$("selector").css("border-bottom-color", "#fff");
```

1. construct your jQuery object which provides callable methods first. In this case, say you got an `#mydiv`, then `$("#mydiv")`
2. call the `.css()` method provided by jQuery to modify specified object's css property values.

Comment: for the curious people who viewed the revision log about my tweaking of contents, I'm a little bit drunk.

Comment: i want to change two or more properties..where must i put the second property

Comment: because comment is not expressive enough, so i am gonna post another answer.

Answer (score 24):

```
$('#elementid').css('border-bottom', 'solid 1px red');
```

Answer (score 13):

to modify more css property values, you may use css object. such as:

```
hilight_css = {"border-bottom-color":"red", 
               "background-color":"#000"};
$(".msg").css(hilight_css);
```

but if the modification code is bloated. you should consider the [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509316/change-border-bottom-color-using-jquery/1509410#1509410) March suggested. do it this way:

first, in your css file:

```
.hilight { border-bottom-color:red; background-color:#000; }
.msg { /* something to make it notifiable */ }
```

second, in your js code:

```
$(".msg").addClass("hilight");
// to bring message block to normal
$(".hilight").removeClass("hilight");
```

if ie 6 is not an issue, you can chain these classes to have more specific selectors.

Answer (score 5):

If you have this in your CSS file:

```
.myApp
{
    border-bottom-color:#FF0000;
}
```

and a div for instance of:

```
<div id="myDiv">test text</div>
```

you can use:

```
$("#myDiv").addClass('myApp');// to add the style

$("#myDiv").removeClass('myApp');// to remove the style
```

or you can just use

```
$("#myDiv").css( 'border-bottom-color','#FF0000');
```

I prefer the first example, keeping all the CSS related items in the CSS files.