# Change all table border colors with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have several instances of inline CSS like the following...

```
<td id="problem_display" style="border-right:solid 2px #378DE5; border-top:solid 2px #378DE5; border-bottom:solid 2px #378DE5; padding:10px;" valign="middle">
```

There are also `<table>` tags like this.  With jQuery, can all of their colors be changed from `#378DE5` to `#5CB811`?  I already have some jQuery working...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var last = $('tbody tr:hidden').length;
    if (last > 0) {
        $("#nextStep").click(function () {
            var x = $("tbody tr:hidden:first");

            console.log(x);
            console.log(last);
            $("tbody tr:hidden:first").show();
            last = $('tbody tr:hidden').length;
            if (last == 0) { 
                $("#nextStep").html('DONE!');
                $("#nextStep").addClass("finished_show_next_button");
                //I want to add the changing of the table/cell borders here.
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In the commented area above, is it possible to do some kind of `str_replace` like PHP does?  Where Javascript/jQuery will scan the document and change all instances of `#378DE5` to `#5CB811`?

A sample table is here...

```
            <table id="problem_area" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr id="problem_header">
                    <td id="problem_title" style="border-right:solid 2px #378DE5; border-bottom:solid 2px #378DE5; padding:10px;" width="50%" align="center"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold; color: #545454;"><?php echo 'Unit ' . $row['unit'] . ', Lesson ' . $row['lesson'] . ': ' . $row['title']; ?></span></td>
                    <td id="notes_title" style="border-left:solid 2px #378DE5; border-bottom:solid 2px #378DE5; padding:10px;" width="50%" align="center"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold; color: #545454;">Notes</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="border_row">
                    <td id="border_cell" style="border:solid 2px #378DE5;"></td>
                    <td id="border_cell" style="border:solid 2px #378DE5;"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="problem_display_row">
                    <td id="problem_display" style="border-right:solid 2px #378DE5; border-top:solid 2px #378DE5; border-bottom:solid 2px #378DE5; padding:10px;" valign="middle">
stuff                       </td>
                    <td id="notes_display" style="border-top:solid 2px #378DE5; border-left:solid 2px #378DE5; border-bottom:solid 2px #378DE5; padding:10px;" valign="middle">
more stuff                      </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="problem_display_work">
                    <td id="problem_display" style="border-right:solid 2px #378DE5; border-top:solid 2px #378DE5; border-bottom:solid 2px #378DE5; padding:10px;" valign="middle">
stuff again                     </td>
                    <td id="notes_display" style="border-top:solid 2px #378DE5; border-left:solid 2px #378DE5; border-bottom:solid 2px #378DE5; padding:10px;" valign="middle">
more stuff again                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="problem_display_work">
                    <td id="problem_display" style="border-right:solid 2px #378DE5; border-top:solid 2px #378DE5; border-bottom:solid 2px #378DE5; padding:10px;" valign="middle">
still more stuff                        </td>
                    <td id="notes_display" style="border-top:solid 2px #378DE5; border-left:solid 2px #378DE5; border-bottom:solid 2px #378DE5; padding:10px;" valign="middle">
still more stuff again                      </td>
                </tr>

            <tbody>
            <tfoot>

                <tr>
                    <td class="show_next_button" id="nextStep" colspan="2">Show Next</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>

        </table>
```

Comment: Why inline CSS? If you can modify the HTML I would start by removing all those styles and creating a separate stylesheet.

Comment: Why jQuery? Is it your HTML? If that's the case, you should be able to edit it and add the styling to the elements you want, a lighter approach than using jQuery after the document has rendered

Comment: @carl-lopez: I already have the above javascript/jQuery doing stuff.  I want the color change when the last iteration is reached (i.e. last == 0).

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509316/change-border-bottom-color-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class can help you easily as follows
give a common class to all the td, tr ,table say "style-border-color"..

```
<td id="problem_title" class="style-border-color" ><?php echo 'Unit ' . $row['unit'] . ', Lesson ' . $row['lesson'] . ': ' . $row['title']; ?></span></td>
```

in your css, add you css code which you have written inline

```
.style-border-color
{
style="border-right:solid 2px #378DE5; border-bottom:solid 2px #378DE5; padding:10px;" width="50%" align="center"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold; color: #545454;"
}
```

then in jquery try following

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $(".style-border-color").css({"border-color":"your-desired-color"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, according to your comment `I want the color change when the last iteration is reached`
. Here is how to change style. Try this?

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/kqB6L/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var last = $('tbody tr:hidden').length;
        if (last > 0) {
        $("#nextStep").click(function () {
            var x = $("tbody tr:hidden:first");

            console.log(x);
            console.log(last);
            $("tbody tr:hidden:first").show();
            last = $('tbody tr:hidden').length;
            if (last == 0) { 
                $("#nextStep").html('DONE!');
                $("#nextStep").addClass("finished_show_next_button");
                //I want to add the changing of the table/cell borders here.
                $("tbody td").each(function(){
                    if($(this).css('border-right')=='2px solid rgb(55, 141, 229)'){
                        $(this).css({'border-right':'2px solid #5CB811'});
                    }
                    if($(this).css('border-top')=='2px solid rgb(55, 141, 229)'){
                        $(this).css({'border-top':'2px solid #5CB811'});
                    }
                    if($(this).css('border-bottom')=='2px solid rgb(55, 141, 229)'){
                        $(this).css({'border-bottom':'2px solid #5CB811'});
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your solution is 95% what I need!  The only issue I'm running into is that if a cell only has border-right and border-top, your code is adding in a border-bottom.  Do you have a way around not adding in borders where there currently aren't any?

Comment: can you post your part of table html code, so that i can check and work around.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution, but it didn't work for some reason.  I'm upvoting it though because it clearly works on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You are you not working with css classes?

You could assign a class that uses the `#378DE5` color and another one for the `#5CB811`. Then, using jQuery iterate through all of the tables and update the classes!

Comment: I could organize everything by classes.  If need be, that's what I'll do.  I like your idea, but I don't have any idea of how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code to replace the color code. Place this where you want to.

```
var styleStr = $("tbody td[style]").getAttribute("style").replace(/#378DE5/g,"#5CB811");

$("tbody td[style]").setAttribute("style",styleStr);
```